# How to get lower and higher 32 bits of a 64-bit integer for gcc inline asm? (ARMV5 platform)

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm, inline-assembly

I have a project on armv5te platform, and I have to rewrite some functions and use assembly code to use enhancement DSP instructions.
I use a lot of int64_t type for accumulators, but I do not have an idea how to pass it for arm instruction SMULL (http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289902800.htm).

How can I pass lower or higher 32-bits of 64 variables to 32-bit register? (I know, that I can use intermediate variable int32_t, but it does not look good).

I know, that compiler would do it for me, but I just write the small function for an example.

```
int64_t testFunc(int64_t acc, int32_t x, int32_t y)
{
   int64_t tmp_acc;

   asm("SMULL %0, %1, %2, %3"
      : "=r"(tmp_acc), "=r"(tmp_acc) // no idea how to pass tmp_acc;
      : "r"(x), "r"(y)
      );

return tmp_acc + acc;
}
```

Comment: "does not look good" might be an important aesthetic concern, but doesn't particularly matter for inline assembly.

Comment: took roughly 30-90 seconds to find the answer on google, an additional 2-5 minutes of reading the gcc docs and googling to find why that answer works.

Comment: [Template modifiers for AArch32 state](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armclang_ref/armclang_ref_agl1517569474771.htm).  You might also want to do a bit more googling.  I've [heard](https://www.infineonforums.com/threads/1817-GCC-no-DSP-support) gcc will use dsp instructions if it believes they are valuable (and available).  If you can avoid using inline asm, you will almost certainly be happier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need and shouldn't use inline asm for this.  The compiler can do even better than `smull`, and use `smlal` to multiply-accumulate with one instruction:

```
int64_t accum(int64_t acc, int32_t x, int32_t y) {
    return acc + x * (int64_t)y;
}
```

which compiles ([with gcc8.2 `-O3 -mcpu=arm10e` on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Aint64_t+testFunc(int64_t+acc,+int32_t+x,+int32_t+y)%0A%7B%0A+++uint32_t+prod_lo,+prod_hi%3B%0A%0A+++asm(%22SMULL+%250,+%251,+%252,+%253%22%0A++++++:+%22%3D%26r%22+(prod_lo),+%22%3D%26r%22(prod_hi)%0A++++++:+%22r%22(x),+%22r%22(y)%0A++++++)%3B%0A%0A++++int64_t+prod+%3D+((int64_t)prod_hi)+%3C%3C+32%3B%0A++++prod+%7C%3D+prod_lo%3B++++++++//+%2B+here+won!'t+optimize+away,+but+%7C+does,+with+gcc%0A++++return+acc+%2B+prod%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint64_t+testFunc2(int64_t+acc,+int32_t+x,+int32_t+y)%0A%7B%0A+++int64_t+prod%3B%0A%0A+++asm(%22SMULL+%25Q0,+%25R0,+%251,+%252%22%0A++++++:+%22%3D%26r%22+(prod)%0A++++++:+%22r%22(x),+%22r%22(y)%0A++++++)%3B%0A%0A++++return+acc+%2B+prod%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint64_t+accum(int64_t+acc,+int32_t+x,+int32_t+y)+%7B%0A++++return+acc+%2B+x+*+(int64_t)y%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:26.81746361465099,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:armg820,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-fverbose-asm+-Wall+-mcpu%3Darm10e',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:100,l:'4',m:51.00369783412573,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang700,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall+--target%3Darm+-mcpu%3Darm10e+-mfloat-abi%3Dhard',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+7.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:100,l:'4',m:48.99630216587428,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:73.18253638534901,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)) to this asm:  (ARM10E is an ARMv5 microarchitecture I picked [from Wikipedia's list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Cores))

```
accum:
    smlal   r0, r1, r3, r2        @, y, x
    bx      lr  @
```

As a bonus, this pure C also compiles efficiently for AArch64.

**https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm**

---

### If you insist on shooting yourself in the foot and using inline asm:

Or in the general case with other instructions, there might be a case where you'd want this.

**First, beware that `smull` output registers aren't allowed to overlap the first input register, so you have to tell the compiler about this.**  An early-clobber constraint on the output operand(s) will do the trick of telling the compiler it can't have inputs in those registers.  I don't see a clean way to tell the compiler that the 2nd input can be in the same register as an output.

This restriction is lifted in ARMv6 and later (see [this Keil documentation](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289902800.htm)) "*Rn must be different from RdLo and RdHi in architectures before ARMv6*", but for ARMv5 compatibility you need to make sure the compiler doesn't violate this when filling in your inline-asm template.

Optimizing compilers can optimize away a shift/OR that combines 32-bit C variables into a 64-bit C variable, when targeting a 32-bit platform.  They already store 64-bit variables as a pair of registers, and in normal cases can figure out there's no actual work to be done in the asm.

**So you can specify a 64-bit input or output as a pair of 32-bit variables.**

```
#include <stdint.h>

int64_t testFunc(int64_t acc, int32_t x, int32_t y)
{
   uint32_t prod_lo, prod_hi;

   asm("SMULL %0, %1, %2, %3"
      : "=&r" (prod_lo), "=&r"(prod_hi)  // early clobber for pre-ARMv6
      : "r"(x), "r"(y)
      );

    int64_t prod = ((int64_t)prod_hi) << 32;
    prod |= prod_lo;        // + here won't optimize away, but | does, with gcc
    return acc + prod;
}
```

Unfortunately the early-clobber means we need 6 total registers, but the ARM calling convention only has 6 call-clobbered registers ([r0..r3, lr, and ip (aka r12)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#ARM_(A32))).  And one of them is LR, which has the return address so we can't lose its value.  Probably not a big deal when inlined into a regular function that already saves/restores several registers.

Again [from Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Aint64_t+testFunc(int64_t+acc,+int32_t+x,+int32_t+y)%0A%7B%0A+++uint32_t+prod_lo,+prod_hi%3B%0A%0A+++asm(%22SMULL+%250,+%251,+%252,+%253%22%0A++++++:+%22%3D%26r%22+(prod_lo),+%22%3D%26r%22(prod_hi)%0A++++++:+%22r%22(x),+%22r%22(y)%0A++++++)%3B%0A%0A++++int64_t+prod+%3D+((int64_t)prod_hi)+%3C%3C+32%3B%0A++++prod+%7C%3D+prod_lo%3B++++++++//+%2B+here+won!'t+optimize+away,+but+%7C+does,+with+gcc%0A++++return+acc+%2B+prod%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint64_t+testFunc2(int64_t+acc,+int32_t+x,+int32_t+y)%0A%7B%0A+++int64_t+prod%3B%0A%0A+++asm(%22SMULL+%25Q0,+%25R0,+%251,+%252%22%0A++++++:+%22%3D%26r%22+(prod)%0A++++++:+%22r%22(x),+%22r%22(y)%0A++++++)%3B%0A%0A++++return+acc+%2B+prod%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint64_t+accum(int64_t+acc,+int32_t+x,+int32_t+y)+%7B%0A++++return+acc+%2B+x+*+(int64_t)y%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:26.81746361465099,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:armg820,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-fverbose-asm+-Wall+-mcpu%3Darm10e',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:100,l:'4',m:51.00369783412573,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang700,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall+--target%3Darm+-mcpu%3Darm10e+-mfloat-abi%3Dhard',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+7.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:100,l:'4',m:48.99630216587428,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:73.18253638534901,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4):

```
@ gcc -O3 output with early-clobber, valid even before ARMv6
testFunc:
    str     lr, [sp, #-4]!    @,         Save return address (link register)
    SMULL ip, lr, r2, r3    @ prod_lo, prod_hi, x, y
    adds    r0, ip, r0      @, prod, acc
    adc     r1, lr, r1        @, prod, acc
    ldr     pc, [sp], #4      @          return by popping the return address into PC


@ gcc -O3 output without early-clobber (&) on output constraints:
@ valid only for ARMv6 and later
testFunc:
    SMULL r3, r2, r2, r3    @ prod_lo, prod_hi, x, y
    adds    r0, r3, r0      @, prod, acc
    adc     r1, r2, r1        @, prod, acc
    bx      lr  @
```

**Or you can use a `"=r"(prod64)` constraint and use modifiers to select which half of `%0` you get.**  Unfortunately, gcc and clang emit less efficient asm for some reason, saving more registers (and maintaining 8-byte stack alignment).  2 instead of 1 for gcc, 4 instead of 2 for clang.

```
// using an int64_t directly with inline asm, using %Q0 and %R0 constraints
// Q is the low half, R is the high half.
int64_t testFunc2(int64_t acc, int32_t x, int32_t y)
{
   int64_t prod;    // gcc and clang seem to want more free registers this way

   asm("SMULL %Q0, %R0, %1, %2"
      : "=&r" (prod)         // early clobber for pre-ARMv6
      : "r"(x), "r"(y)
      );

    return acc + prod;
}
```

again compiled with gcc `-O3 -mcpu=arm10e`.  (clang saves/restores 4 registers)

```
@ gcc -O3 with the early-clobber so it's safe on ARMv5
testFunc2:
    push    {r4, r5}        @
    SMULL r4, r5, r2, r3    @ prod, x, y
    adds    r0, r4, r0      @, prod, acc
    adc     r1, r5, r1        @, prod, acc
    pop     {r4, r5}  @
    bx      lr  @
```

So for some reason it seems to be more efficient to manually handle the halves of a 64-bit integer with current gcc and clang.  This is obviously a missed optimization bug.